Remove and reinstall counter with under mount sink
My dishwasher needs to be pulled out but gets stuck on flooring underneath. I know that the back feet are getting stuck on loose flooring because I witnessed this before the dishwasher was installed, and the DW was installed before the countertop.  I can see that the front feet are clear and are able to slide on the proper kitchen flooring.  I have disconnected the drain hose, the supply line, and the power line, and pushed them through into the area behind the DW to be sure that it is not getting caught on those items.
I can move the DW about 6" forward, but then it gets caught.  Then I can move it back, but only 3" or so, before it gets caught again.  The hoses in both position can easily move in and out so it is not the connections getting caught up.  I cannot guarantee that it is the flooring so please move beyond that claim and take my question for what it is worth.
I am needing to remove the counter in order to access the back of the dishwasher, and get it free of the cabinet space in order to make a repair.
There is an undermount sink and kitchen faucet on the counter, which is solid surface and 1.25” thick or so. I think I should be able to get the counter off and leave the sink in place. Just wondering if anyone has done this or has some advice.

dishwashers have adjustable feet or rollers on the bottom. you may be able to adjust the feet up, to give enough space to remove the DW without removing the counter top..

Pictures of the floor stopping the dishwasher and how the sink is mounted, might give ideas to someone.  The sink might have adhesive and a sealer to the counter, making removing it harder.

This shouldn't have been reopened. We have almost no information about the sink mounting mechanism, how the countertop is anchored, or its overall configuration. It's also a very vague question. I'd love to help, but the primary issue with the post was never the factuality of the stuck dishwasher.

True that the problem of the dishwasher is not actually relevant to my question.  Anyway, I was able to remove the counter top, leaving the undermount sink installed (as well as the faucet).  A quick fix of the problem and remounted the countertop.  Now I can remove and reinstall the dishwasher as needed without removing the countertop in the future.
